# work perfectly in python 2.7.3 but error in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, when I run this code in python 2.7.3 with command ./randline.py test.txt this code works fine. However when I try to run this code in python 3 I got an error message "/usr/bin/python: can't open file '3': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

```
import random, sys
 from optparse import OptionParser

class randline:
   def __init__(self, filename):
       f = open(filename, 'r')
       self.lines = f.readlines()
       f.close()

   def chooseline(self):
       return random.choice(self.lines)

def main():
   version_msg = "%prog 2.0"
   usage_msg = """%prog [OPTION]... FILE

Output randomly selected lines from FILE."""

   parser = OptionParser(version=version_msg,
                      usage=usage_msg)
   parser.add_option("-n", "--numlines",
                  action="store", dest="numlines", default=1,
                  help="output NUMLINES lines (default 1)")
   options, args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

   try:
       numlines = int(options.numlines)
   except:
       parser.error("invalid NUMLINES: {0}".
                    format(options.numlines))
   if numlines < 0:
       parser.error("negative count: {0}".
                 format(numlines))
   if len(args) != 1:
       parser.error("wrong number of operands")
   input_file = args[0]

   try:
       generator = randline(input_file)
       for index in range(numlines):
           sys.stdout.write(generator.chooseline())
   except IOError as (errno, strerror):
       parser.error("I/O error({0}): {1}".
                    format(errno, strerror))

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Is there any thing wrong with this code for python 3 interpreter?

Comment: Can you fix your indentation?

Comment: look for where you said `/usr/bin/python 3` instead of `/usr/bin/python3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are running `python 3` (with a space). You should use `python3` instead.

Comment: if I remove the space I got a message "-bash: ./randline.py: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Comment: Do you have python3 installed at all?

Comment: how do I check if I have it installed or not? I am using computer in my school. I thought the default is 2.7.3, not sure about the 3

Comment: Then depending on if you have `/usr/local/cs/bin` in $PATH, you can type either `python3.3 ./randline.py test.txt` or `/usr/local/cs/bin/python3.3 ./randline.py test.txt`. (To see your $PATH, you can do `echo $PATH`.)

Comment: okay... this is weird. When I enter command python3 directly in the terminal, it works just find. However, when I change the path in the code, it just doesn't work at all. I'll contact the helpdesk. thx man. btw is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: I didn't run it but looks ok, only has some stylistic issues.

Comment: Okay. I just asked the helpdesk, and he perform some magic and it works :) However, I got an error w/ my code it says "    except IOError as (errno, strerror):
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"  there's "^" below the opening bracket

Comment: nvm. just found out that python 2 got dif syntax compare to python 3. thx man :)

Answer (score 0):

Since python2.7.3 and python3.* have different syntax, codes work using python2.7.3 and then may not work using python3.*. For example

**print 'hello world'**
works using python2.7.3 but receives error using python3.*. To run it, we have to use **print('Hello world')**

So just change the syntax to python3.* format. But my suggestion is to use python2.7.3 to run your code.